# VBA Userform - Issue for filterting because of periods/comma

Tags: excel, vba, filter, userform

I have an userform that lets users input a number, and then a code that applies a filter to a range, based on the value of that number. Basically, it shows only the values that are superior to that number.

However, I have an issue with decimals. When I enter "1", the code works properly, but when I enter "1,1", it shows nothing. It also does not work when I input (1.1).

I figured out that was because I'm located in France, where we use commas to separate the numbers instead of periods. How could I let any user input numbers like "1,2" in the UserForm and then properly filter the desired range?

Please find my current code below: (it also contains information regarding another filter, but this one works properly).

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()

'this is the code that runs when I say filter

Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("main")
Dim IntYields As Integer


ws.Cells(3, 4).Value = Filter_names.Sector_List.Value

With ws.Cells(3, 5)
    .Value = Filter_names.Yields_Input.Value
    .NumberFormat = "0.00"
    .Value = .Value
    .Value = CDbl(.Value)
End With

If IsEmpty(Range("E3").Value) = True Then
      ws.Cells(3, 5).Value = 0
End If

'double filter
ws.Range("$A$9:$H$23500").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Range("D3").Value
ws.Range("$A$9:$H$23500").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=">=" & Range("E3").Value
    
'close the userform
Unload Filter_names


End Sub
```

Thanks for your help, let me know if you need anything else from my side

[screenshot of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgZZu.png)

Comment: Could you share some sample data or an image of the data. BTW, you are aware that with `Field:=6` you are filtering by column `F`?

Comment: Yes, I intend to filter column F.
Sure, i'll edit my initial post with a picture

Comment: Is `Filter_names.Sector_List` a control on your form?  If so, `Filter_names.Sector_List.Value` is probably a string.  Since VBA is heavily US-EN biased I guess the following code is not converting a string containing `,` as the decimal separator to a number

Comment: Yes indeed, both yields_input.value & sector_list.value are controls on my userform. That's why I'm trying to find a way to convert this string as a number that can be used as a reference to filter cells that are written with, as the decimal separator. I've tried several things in my code, with things like number format, or .value, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Found a workaround, not pretty but I multiply the numbers that I want to filter by 100 to remove the decimals, and then I can filter them..